# Pattern matching 'like' on primary key in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, nosql, cql, cql3, cassandra-3.0

In Cassandra **'like'** can be used to find matching results satisfying the search pattern on SASI indexed columns, it is working perfectly well, but how to use like on primary keys.

this is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE indexxx (
    title VARCHAR,
    PRIMARY KEY (title));
```

**Indexing is not allowed on primary keys**,

```
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX testtt ON indexxx (title) USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex' WITH OPTIONS = {'mode': 'CONTAINS', 'analyzer_class': 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.analyzer.StandardAnalyzer', 'case_sensitive': 'false'};



InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Cannot create secondary index on partition key column title"
```

when tried to use like without sasi indexing,

```
select * from indexxx  where title like '%kkk%' ;

InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="LIKE restriction is only supported on properly indexed columns. title LIKE '%kkk%' is not valid."
```

Comment: Any answer this issue?

Answer (score 7):

It’s not possible to use LIKE clause on partition column of primary key. This is because partition value is always hashed and only the corresponding token is used while searching.

However you can use LIKE clause on clustering columns or any other non collection columns (not set, map or list) with help of SASI index.

Comment: Any questions/comments on the solution provided? Otherwise remember to accept/upvote the solution provided.

Answer (score 1):

You can create another column that will contain the same value as title call it title_sasi, and apply index on this new column.

Table structure will be

```
CREATE TABLE indexxx (
    title VARCHAR,
    title_sasi VARCHAR,
    PRIMARY KEY (title));
```

Index:

```
CREATE CUSTOM INDEX testtt ON indexxx (title_sasi) USING 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.SASIIndex' WITH OPTIONS = {'mode': 'CONTAINS', 'analyzer_class': 'org.apache.cassandra.index.sasi.analyzer.StandardAnalyzer', 'case_sensitive': 'false'};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SASI annotaion or query to use like(contains) on non-primary attributes.
Annotation support is available in 2.2.7.RELEASE spring-data release

```
@Indexed
@SASI(indexMode = IndexMode.CONTAINS)
@SASI.StandardAnalyzed
```